# Sharing sessions between server1(Laravel) and server2(React)

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, session

I have a peculiar case on my hands and in need of help/guidance.

I have main app coded with Laravel on example.com.
example.com/dashboard is another server and serves single page app coded with React and back-end driven by Lumen (another server as well).

Server A - main app (Laravel), example.com
Server B - dashboard (React), example.com/dashboard
Server C - dashboard back-end (Lumen), dashboard.example.com

The challenge is knowing about signed in user between Server A and Server B applications. B and C are fine as requests are authenticated via a stateless mechanism such as API tokens.

However, how I do the following:

User signs in at example.com (Server A), clicks on example.com/dashboard (Server B) and application at Server B (React) resumes user session.

I'm using Redis with Laravel.

The request to Server B will have Cookie header which I assume will allow me to resume session, however how do I resume with React?

Comment: Can't you have Server A issue a valid API token that can be accepted by Server B and C ? This way you wouldn't need  a session at all.

Comment: An option. However that raises a challenge of how do I pass API token to server B via simple <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a> ?

Comment: If you set a cookie on the `/` of `example.com` then it should be available generally. Probably not the most elegant solution though.